# Can not upload files via vsftpd server for virtual_user mode

Tags: linux, ftp, configuration, centos7, vsftpd

My server is Centos 7. My config file [vsftp.conf](http://pastebin.com/a8mh95AH)

I use

```
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```

to make sure use virtual user privilages.
And I use root privilage to upload

```
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=root
local_root=/var/www/html/
```

But I still meet error of upload&create file.

```
[07:00:08] [R] 220 Welcome to vivian FTP service.
[07:00:08] [R] USER someone
[07:00:08] [R] 331 Please specify the password.
[07:00:08] [R] PASS (hidden)
[07:00:15] [R] 530 Login incorrect.
[07:00:15] [R] transmit fail (Connection closed by server)
```

I even open the annoymous upload file right.

```
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

The SEliux is not active on server.

How to make virtual users can upload files.